# C - singleton instantiated inside or outside module?

Tags: c, architecture, module

What limitations are imposed when a C module

1. instantiates its own core `struct` (as a singleton) and user code accesses this using `extern`

VS.

2. has user code instantiate the singleton `struct` instead

?

For example, one limitation of the former is that the user cannot choose the allocation method.

**EDIT** The reason for the question is that I have hit some walls with approach no. 1 in the past (C language limitations) but have now forgotten what they were!

Comment: Can you show some code or explain what you mean by "instantiating singleton" in the context of C?

Comment: @ci_ I'm trying to keep the question general. The singleton is just a given struct instance. In this case, the struct is core to the whole library, and only one such struct instance need ever exist. Question updated a little.

Comment: Please refer this link [How to create a Singleton in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/803690/5184415)

Comment: @venki Thanks, but unfortunately that really doesn't begin to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want make absolutely sure, that the singleton "stays single", let the module handle its creation.
2. If the singleton's implementation details shall stay hidden, you also want to let the module handle it and optionally just return an opaque pointer to the singleton's *internal* `struct`, so the user has nothing more than a "handle". The handle however is not necessary as its a singleton :-).